# Spring Data failed to lazily initialize a collection of role, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am making an API with Spring Boot and I never seem to manage to initialize lazy collections. The only solution that has ever worked for me is changing it to eager, but that is no solution.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    String email;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = LAZY)
    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    public UserEntity(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

```
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Component
public class AuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if(authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()){
            String email = authentication.getName();
            UserEntity user = userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElse(new UserEntity(email));
            user.getRoles().clear();
            user.getRoles().addAll(authentication.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

These are my two classes. A user entity and a filter that will create user from an authentication object. When the line `user.getRoles().clear();` is called, I get the famous error `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ch.ciip.ressources.api.user.UserEntity.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session`.

From my understanding, Spring Data will create a proxy for each lazy relation, and will only fetch the data once it is accessed. But to access it it needs a session and apparently, Spring is not able to create a session when accessing a proxy, however, it has no problem doing it when I call save on a repository.

What I've tried is :

- `@Transactional` from both `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` and `javax.transaction.Transactional`. But it changes absolutely nothing.
- Change fetch type to `EAGER`. This method works, but it is not what I want to do.
- Change `enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true`to true in application.properties file. This method is not recommended, so I will not try it.
- Calling a method on the lazy collection before trying to modify it. For example calling `user.getRoles().size();` so it gets initialized. But it does not work.
- Calling `Hibernate.initialize(user.getRoles());` to initialize the collection. But it does not work.

I wonder why Spring says `No Session` because it does create a session for the `userRepository.findByEmail(email)` as well as for `userRepository.save(user)`.

I could create an entitymanager manually and use it to fetch/persist my entities. But that is not the goal as I'm using Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the method `public`, i.e.:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if(authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()){
        String email = authentication.getName();
        UserEntity user = userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElse(new UserEntity(email));
        user.getRoles().clear();
        user.getRoles().addAll(authentication.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: I get an error if I make it public `Exception starting filter [authFilter] java.lang.NullPointerException: null ... One or more Filters failed to start.`. What is the reasoning behind making it public?

Comment: @Servietsky the cause is something different now. The method should be public for `@Transactional` to work (a proxy of a bean has to be created by spring)

Comment: @Servietsky As @Andronicus rightly pointed out, making it `public` will enable it to be proxied which is required for `@Transactional` to work. But there is an exception to it. If you use AspectJ for proxying instead of default Spring proxy AOP then the modifier can stay as `protected`.

Comment: @Andronicus As soon as I add a `@Transactional` anywhere in a public method in my `OncePerRequestFilter` it fails. I've tried putting the `@Transactional` inside a public method within the entity. `@Transactional public void setRoles(Set<String> roles) { this.roles.clear(); this.roles.addAll(roles); }`. And I still get the same error `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role`.

Comment: @Servietsky I would suggest removing the `@Transactional` from the filter and moving it to a separate @service class. Inject the service class into the filter and use it.

Comment: The reason it is failing maybe because of the fact that the filter is chaining and the transaction is not completed within a point of time or something along that line.

Comment: @Servietsky I must agree with ThirumalaiParthasarathi. My solution takes care of LazyInitializationException and problems around AOP. I don't know how it works when combined with filtered. Besides mixing everything in a single method is certainly not a good practice

Comment: This, `Inject the service class into the filter and use it`, did the trick. I've read somewhere `Filter is not instantiated in Spring Container. It is instantiated in the Web Application Container so sessionFactory will always be null thus the NullPointerException.`. So I guess the @Service I created separately is instantiated with the Spring Container and that's why it works! Thank you both very much. This issue was quite the pain and I understand it much better now.

Comment: @Servietsky no problem, consider accepting the answer;>

Answer (score 2):

Creating a separate service class and injecting it into this filter is a workaround i can propose.

```
@Service
class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void findUserByEmailAndAddRoles(String email, Set<String> authorities) {
        UserEntity user = userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                   .orElse(new UserEntity(email));
        user.getRoles().clear();
        user.getRoles().addAll(authorities);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Then use this in your filter

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if(authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()){
        String email = authentication.getName();
        Set<String> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
           .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        userService.findUserByEmailAndAddRoles(email, authorities);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```